# Work profile - redirect hyperlinks to normal profile apps

Tags: hyperlinks, work-profiles

I am using a work profile (set up via Insular) in order to clone some apps. I have an issue I can't seem to find any info about on the internet and I'm hoping someone can help me here. I am using ColorOS on Android 13 if that has any importance.

I have a cloned app that may have links in it. Because I have no browser on my work profile, it will just refuse to open the links, saying that I don't have any app that can do it. I don't want to pollute my phone with a second instance of my browser that I don't need.

**Issue:** How can I tell my work profile apps to open links with an app outside of work profile? Weirdly enough it sometimes work??? Like some links from the work app will open just fine in Firefox from normal profile. But most won't especially YouTube links won't ever open the YT app, or browser for that matter.